# Unable to install Jupyter notebook extension in VS code version 1.35

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, version

My system(Mac) is an older version ( 10.9.2 ), so I couldn't install the newest version of the VS Code (1.5) in this. although I did find an older version of VS Code from the archive- may 2019 (version 1.35) which worked with the older version of mac.
the problem is - it is unable to install Jupyter notebook extension as that's only supported on higher/newer version of VS code and mine is older. and I can't install the newer version because my system is not 10.10+
I have tried installing Jupyter separately or installing from pip, still, my .ipynb files don't work and it says this language isn't supported. and on clicking Jupyter extension installation, it says it is not supported for VS Code version 1.35.

is there any option to make jupyter notebook work in this older version of VS Code? Other than converting .ipynb files to .py files and make it work?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Regards,

Richa